# uploading image using C# Http post

Tags: c#, python, image, http, post

This Python program uploads an image to a url. I need same thing but in C#. How can I do this? I am using win-forms.

The program:

```
fin =  open(file_path, 'rb')
files = {'file': fin}

try:<br>
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, verify = False)
finally:
    fin.close()

json_data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a million examples of this, but to get you the right one, we need to know where and how this is running. asp.net, forms, mvc, core, console, etc.

Comment: I am running win-forms application

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of examples around but try this one it may work for ya.

```
private byte[] GetFileByteArray(string filename)
  {
   FileStream oFileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

   // Create a byte array of file size.
   byte[] FileByteArrayData = new byte[oFileStream.Length];

   //Read file in bytes from stream into the byte array
   oFileStream.Read(FileByteArrayData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(oFileStream.Length));

   //Close the File Stream
   oFileStream.Close();

   return FileByteArrayData; //return the byte data
  }
```

// This above method return the file's Byte array then you need to call UploadVideoFile method.

```
public string UploadVideoFile(string URL, byte[] VideoFileData)
    {
      string Response = null;
      HttpWebRequest WebReq = null;
      HttpWebResponse WebRes = null;
      StreamReader StreamResponseReader = null;
      Stream requestStream = null;
      try
      {
        WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.Accept = "*/*";
        WebReq.Timeout = 50000;
        WebReq.KeepAlive = false;
        WebReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        WebReq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        WebReq.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";
        WebReq.ContentLength = VideoFileData.Length;


        requestStream = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(VideoFileData, 0, VideoFileData.Length);

        requestStream.Close();

        WebRes = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
        StreamResponseReader = new StreamReader(WebRes.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        Response = StreamResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
      }
      catch
      {
        throw;
      }
      finally
      {
        if (WebReq != null)
        {
          WebReq.Abort();
          WebReq = null;
        }
        if (WebRes != null)
        {
          WebRes.Close();
          WebRes = null;
        }
        if (StreamResponseReader != null)
        {
          StreamResponseReader.Close();
          StreamResponseReader = null;
        }
        if (requestStream != null)
        {
          requestStream = null;
        }
      }


      return Response;
    }
```

Use this link for reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9be81392-71b6-4424-aed4-0627f041ba2e/how-to-upload-a-image-file-via-http-request-using-cnet?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

Comment: {System.Net.WebException: Temel alınan bağlantı kapatıldı: Gönderme işleminde beklenmeyen hata oluştu. ---> System.IO.IOException: Aktarma bağlantısından veriler okunamadı: Varolan bir bağlantı uzaktaki bir ana bilgisayar tarafından zorla kapatıldı. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Varolan bir bağlantı uzaktaki bir ana bilgisayar tarafından zorla kapatıldı
   konum: System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   konum: System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Comment: I get this error when  WebReq.GetRequestStream() is runing

Comment: Apparently your file was not sent properly. Check again that you are reading the file and sending it the request as a byte array. If your problem is resolved accept my answer, thanks!